# Index of bits in 8-Bit variable

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I have an 8-Bit variable and I want to get the index of each 1-Bit.
For 00000011 the indices would only be 1 and 2. To get the indices  I would use a simple for loop and check whether a bit is 1- at a given position.

My approach will always need 8-iterations. Can this be done more efficiently?

Comment: You need up to 8 values as result - so really there nothing more efficient than iterate each bit. Table of results is standard alternative but eventually something will need to iterate over result anyway. You may want to clarify what type of efficiency you are looking for

Comment: Hmm....Lets say there are only up to 4 1-Bits. Could I speed up the calculation by calculating the index of the least significant bit, change that bit to 0 and calculate the least significant bit again until I got all the indices ?

Comment: Measure yourself and see. There is no way to even guess anything without code you've tried. See http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ for guidance on asking performance questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it would accelerate your issue but you could shift your 8 bit variable (if its unsigned) at every iteration and test if the value is zero for early loop exit